# Regular expression extractor

Tags: jmeter

I need to extract the value of IcsAuthV1 in following GET request in Jmeter

GET http://INVRLX61CEP100:16006/saas/tokenlogin?IcsAuthV1=mAUoOnWt9B4wTuwkCJ6esHO5K1wUNNUsRAoucFLg4UwM_s3rhoHxUxstMPuaHgJuUBhaZlCAz9F1DkTFW3eGFKlUznZ5aHy1RA238ihDTXU

what will be the regular expression for extracting IcsAuthV1 from this ??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Reg Exp extractor type in:
Reference name: variableYouWillWriteTo
Regular Expression: IcsAuthV1=(.+)
Template: $1$
And do not forget to set Field to check as URL. That should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request.
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Field to check: `URL`
   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `token`
   - Regular Expression: `=(.*)`
   - Template: `$1$`

[image: Regular Expression Extractor configuration]

Refer extracted value as `${token}` where required.

You can use [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination to see JMeter Variables values, it is quite helpful to identify what is extracted.

Moreover, if you applying regular expression to response body, you can switch View Results Tree listener to RegExp Tester view and test your regular expressions directly against response without having to re-run the request. See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for more recommendations on getting to the bottom of unexpected JMeter test behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Dmitri T.

- Regular Expression : IcsAuthV1=(.*)

explanation:

- dot (.) means match any character
- wildcard (*) means zero or more occurrences

please refer to picture below:

[image]